# How to add an Array to an Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the following code:

```
var optionsChart = {
    data: [{
        type: "bla",
        dataPoints: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 3
        }, {
            x: 1,
            y: 2
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 4
        }]
    },
    etc...
}
```

Now I tried to generate the Datas in the **dataPoints** field dynamically. I have an Array like this:

```
dataArray = [[1,3], [1,2],[3,4]];
```

I try to insert his after **dataPoints**, but when doing this it needs to be exactly like in the code above, but I don't know how to do that.

Any suggestions here? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this way:

```
optionsChart.data[0].dataPoints.push(dataArray.map(function (obj) {
    return {
        x: obj[0],
        y: obj[1]
    };
}));
```

Or try this way:

```
optionsChart.data[0].dataPoints = dataArray.map(function (obj) {
    return {
        x: obj[0],
        y: obj[1]
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

```
optionsChart.data[0].dataPoints.push(dataArray.map(function(t) {
         return {x: t[0], y: t[1]};
}));
```

---